# Azure PowerShell Login: browser based authentication dialog failed to complete

Tags: azure, adal, azure-powershell

I'm getting this error when running `Login-AzureRmAccount` in PowerShell:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The request could not be 
processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication.AadAuthenticationFailedException,Microsoft.Azure.Comm 
   ands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand
```

I see the login window pop up briefly, but it closes immediately and this error message displays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out my proxy settings were preventing me from connecting to the internet.  Once I corrected my proxy settings I was able to log into Azure as expected.  Not sure what the "invalid syntax" error is all about...

Comment: Can you comment on what was wrong with your proxy settings?

Comment: @BobbyA I can't remember for sure; most likely I had it disabled when I was at work or enabled when I was at home.

Answer (score 1):

Run add-azureaccount
it will ask for credential, enter the credential.
then run Connect-azAccount it will again ask for the credential, provide the credentials and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Go to Start -> Internet Properties and delete all browsing history (worked for me).  Likely expired cookies/cache.